# EditText Value in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-edittext

I have a custom dialog with me. In which an editText id there, I am reading input through editText, putting the input to a string. This code is followed by a thread (sub) to handle one url. I want to use this string in the thread mentioned. But the thread is getting invoked before I type to the editText. How can i dynamically use the same text from the userinput inside the thread?  Thanks in advance..

public void onClick(View v) 
     {

```
     switch (v.getId()) 
        {
        case R.id.i1:
            MyDevice.getInstance().currentUserImageId=R.drawable.jerry1;
            MyDevice.getInstance().userName="You";
            MyDevice.getInstance().facebook=0;


            this.finish();
            break;



        case R.id.i2:
            MyDevice.getInstance().currentUserImageId=R.drawable.chaplin1;
            MyDevice.getInstance().userName="You";
            MyDevice.getInstance().facebook=0;
            this.finish();
            break;



        case R.id.i3:
            MyDevice.getInstance().currentUserImageId=R.drawable.budy;
            MyDevice.getInstance().userName="You";
            MyDevice.getInstance().facebook=0;

            this.finish();
            break;

        case R.id.facebook:


            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.usernamefbdialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Enter Facebook Username");


            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.done);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                     EditText edit=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.username);
                     text=edit.getText().toString();

                        dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });



            dialog.show();





            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    try
                    {                           

                    MyDevice.getInstance().bitmap=getUserPic(text);
                    MyDevice.getInstance().facebook=1;
                    ImageView facebookImg=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.facebookimg);
                    facebookImg.setImageBitmap(MyDevice.getInstance().bitmap);  

                    } 

                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            thread.start(); 


                break;  









         }

}
```

Comment: Post the code you have so its easier for us to understand what you have and where your problem is

Comment: Keep a reference of created Thread and pass it the value when needed through a setter. As codeMagic says, if you post your code it will be easier for us to help.

Comment: Use the "edit" button under your post to add your code there...much easier to read

Comment: Yes but you can edit and put the code from your comment into your question and format it so we can read it easier. Also, if you need to show an image you can post a link and someone can add it

Comment: yes. Thanks dude. Added the code. Now what I really want is when the input through edit text is recieved, i want to use it in the next thread, to put the input for getUserPic method. When code runs, it seems like thread runs in between, when we are typing the input for the edit text, using its initial value for the mentioned string. How can I dynamically get that value so that the thread uses the exact value the time user typed it! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is run the Thread from within the button click event, that way it runs after you get the text. See your modified code below.
The events that happen to the String occur in this order.
1. Create the String
2. Set the String equal to the edit text String
3. Start the Thread and use the String

```
        final String theStringYouWantToUseInTheThread = null;       
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                try
                {                           
                //use theStringYouWantToUseInTheThread here
                MyDevice.getInstance().bitmap=getUserPic(text);
                MyDevice.getInstance().facebook=1;
                ImageView facebookImg=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.facebookimg);
                facebookImg.setImageBitmap(MyDevice.getInstance().bitmap);  

                } 

                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                 EditText edit=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.username);
                 theStringYouWantToUseInTheThread = edit.getText().toString();
                 thread.start();
                 dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();







        thread.start();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude... Worked really fast!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if I understand but this sentence "How can i dynamically use the same text from the userinput inside the thread?"sounds like you want to implement a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) on your `EditText`

```
public class TempWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
    {   
                 // you can update something here
    }
}
```

But if you check for a valid value in your `EditText` when clicking the `Button` and only start your `Thread` then, it should do what you want. If this doesn't work then please clarify your problem and show where you start the `Thread` and how it is implemented

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.. When  I Put that Thread inside the click listener (inside the dialog), as suggested by ACR Development, it worked.